# XPATH find all parent nodes with only empty children

Tags: html, xpath

I am looking for a xpath query to find all parent nodes that only have empty children. See the following example

```
<table>
   <tr><td>text</td></tr> <!-- this one should not be matched -->
   <tr><td>text</td><td></tr> <!-- not matched -->
   <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> <!-- this one should be matched -->
</table>
```

This query should only match those elements that only have empty children, and it does not need to work for arbitary depth, just one level down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//*[* and not(*[node()])]` selects all elements with at least one child element but not any child element that has child nodes.

If you consider an element with whitespace only content to be empty then use `//*[* and not(*[*]) and not(*[not(*) and normalize-space()])]`.

Comment: I would consider whitespace only to be empty.